# How can I recover PbNO3 from PbI2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I'm a chemistry school teacher.

I want to know how to recover lead Nitrate from the ppt of PbI2.

I know I can do it using conc HNO3 but I do not know if NO or HI will form. Also I would need a guide on the conditions of the reaction.

I don't want to dispose the lead if I can avoid that.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The reaction is given [here](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-9711).

$$\ce{3PbI2 + 8HNO3 ->[\Delta] 3Pb(NO3)2 + 3I2 + 2NO + 4H2O}$$

> Lead(II) iodide react with nitric acid to produce  lead(II) nitrate,
>   iodine, nitrogen monoxide and water. Nitric acid - 30% solution. The
>   reaction takes place in a boiling solution.